# How To Copy Files Around FTP Using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am tring to copy a file from one folder to another using the php ftp functions.

e.g

**Copy This File:** httpdocs/user_images/Services/File 1.jpg

**To:** httpdocs/user_images/folder11

i have tried to use ftp_fput but i am not have any luck with it.

Comment: You'd actually have to be running a FTP server for this to work, and have appropriate read/write permissions for both the username you're logging into the FTP server with, and the user you're running the PHP script as. As rockerest says, for copying files around on the same machine, just use the `copy()` function. FTP is for "external" transfers between two distinct machines.

Comment: Don't think that's a one step process.  May need to do a `ftp_get` then `ftp_put`. Is FTP your only option for accessing the remote server?

Comment: Yes that is the way i am trying to do it now but it cannot find the TEMPFOLDER

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the manual page on `ftp_put` on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php):

```
<?php 
// bool ftp_copy  ( resource $ftp_stream  , string $initialpath, string $newpath, string $imagename ) 
function ftp_copy($conn_distant , $pathftp , $pathftpimg ,$img){ 
        // on recupere l'image puis on la repose dans le nouveau folder 
        if(ftp_get($conn_distant, TEMPFOLDER.$img, $pathftp.'/'.$img ,FTP_BINARY)){ 
                if(ftp_put($conn_distant, $pathftpimg.'/'.$img ,TEMPFOLDER.$img , FTP_BINARY)){ 
                        unlink(TEMPFOLDER.$img) ;                                              
                } else{                                
                        return false; 
                } 

        }else{ 
                return false ; 
        } 
        return true ; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I am now getting the following error

ftp_get(TEMPFOLDERFile_1.jpg) [<a href='function.ftp-get'>function.ftp-get</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Comment: Are the login credentials valid? This just downloads the file, then uploads it somewhere else. It may not be the best solution for large files.

Comment: Yes because all my other features are working fine. Its acting on like it cannot find the TEMPFOLDER

Comment: That's because you have to set that yourself. Declare a constant TEMPFOLDER that points to a writable temp folder.

Comment: now i am getting a open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/httpdocs/temp/File_1.jpg)

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps a little known fact: the copy() function in PHP can be used to copy files to an FTP server, though without as much control as you get by using the ftp-specific functions.

In other words, this can do the job:

```
if(copy('local/file.img', 'ftp://user:password@ftp.example.com/remote/dir/file.img')) {
  echo "It worked!!!";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Comment: I tried this method, but for some reason it's only copying part of the file, a little more than half. The copied file will stop mid-word about 500 lines in (it's an 800 line csv). Haven't been able to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're actually moving files between servers or to somewhere that PHP doesn't have access, use [copy()(php)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
<?
copy('httpdocs/user_images/Services/File 1.jpg', 'httpdocs/user_images/folder11/File 1.jpg');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

file copy: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 1):

the Copy Function will not work. You need to use ftp_get () and ftp_put() functions in order to achieve this task