# cpanel allow write files to another user folder

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to setup a way where i can copy or write files from one user account to another user account folder using php. Here is the example

```
<?php 
   copy('texttest.txt','/home/username/public_html/domain.com/texttest.txt');
?>
```

I get permission denied error. I have disabled apache mod_userdir protection. I can access the file from the folder but cannot write to the folder. I am looking for a non-cURL or Cron way. just using simply like copy() or move_uploaded_file() as this is the requirement. Anyone can help with this in setting up permissions or any suggestions?

Comment: its not really a php issue, if your on Linux you can do a bind mount, for the folder.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount

Comment: Thanks your solution works when it comes to uploading but i needed access as i will also need to use rename() function to rename the files in other user directory. because there are some files i dont have in my current user dir. Whats your suggestion?

Comment: add both users to the same group and then make the files part of the group with `chgrp()` ( might need to be root, not sure ) with the correct permissions on the group bit `chmod()` both users should be able to access the files.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php, if php cant run `chgrp` you might have to change the public permissions, but i would only do that as a last resort, which should be ok if its outside of the webroot of the site, because then the containing folder will still be unreachable by the public.

Comment: Other then that you could read them and do copy, but that depends on your specific use for said files.  It's more a matter of getting the permissions right on the file then anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by [php FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) extension, you can see example on these reference.

[How To Copy Files Around FTP Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853269/how-to-copy-files-around-ftp-using-php)

[php upload file from server to another via FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306975/php-upload-file-from-server-to-another-via-ftp)